# UIView.animateWithDuration pausing applicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation, appdelegate

normally  i try to find find on my own a solution, but this time i don't know.
I'm sorry, if i do any mistakes. I'm new to swift and also new to stack overflow.

I'm doing a normal animation of a rectangle (called landscape), which repeats itself, until i say otherwise.

```
func startAnimationReact() {
    let duration = 5.0
    let options = (UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat |
        UIViewAnimationOptions.BeginFromCurrentState)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, options: options, animations: {
            self.landscape.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.heightDisplay-50, width: 50, height: 50)
            }, completion: {
            finished in
            if !finished {
            }
        }
    )
}
```

I already found thru Apples Documentation, that i can pause and resume it with:

```
func stopAnimation() {
    pausedTime = self.landscape.layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), fromLayer: nil)
    self.landscape.layer.speed = 0.0
    self.landscape.layer.timeOffset = pausedTime
    }

func resumeAnimation() {
    self.landscape.layer.speed = 1.0
    self.landscape.layer.timeOffset = 0.0
    self.landscape.layer.beginTime = 0.0
    timeSincePause = self.landscape.layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), fromLayer: nil) - pausedTime
    self.landscape.layer.beginTime = timeSincePause
}
```

And it works. 
But now i want, to call the stopAnimation in applicationDidEnterBackground(), to keep it at the same position, when i come back. But it's not working, it rather seems that the app is automatically removing the animation.

Anyone got an idea? I would appreciate any solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574974/continue-operation-when-app-did-enter-background-on-ios