# Best practice to call a function in NSUserdefaults for parsing data for Watchkit/Today Widget?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I was wondering what the best practice for calling a function using NSUserdefaults is?

So basically I have a function in my main data model in my app that parses some data from an API.

I was able to pass the return value of this function through NSUserdefaults to transfer the data from my main app to my WatchKit app. However it only passes data when the App has been opened. How best can I call the function, to parse data from the API using Watchkit on it's own? (Like a background app open) I'm a bit confused.

Kind Regards,

Jack

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question doesn't make much sense.

In WatchKit 1.0, the watch app is really just a second screen for your iPhone, managed by different types of controller objects.

What is it that you are trying to communicate to the watch, what do you want the watch to do with it?

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply & welcome. 
Hi There @DuncanC basically my app pulls some information from an API and parses it into a string, I want to be able to access this information on my watch.

So for example 

_iphone app_ pulls down IP Address of a server using a function A

_watckit app_ displays Up to date  IP Address pulled down from function A

So how do I execute Function A in the background using my Watchkit app, Without having user to physically open the iPhone app.

Comment: Please check my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/31994232

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your comments make things a little clearer.

You want to be able to have code that runs in your watch app that ask the phone for information.

If your watch app is running in a `WKInterfaceController`, you can use the `WKInterfaceController`  method `openParentApplication` to send a request to the iPhone and get back a reply dictionary. If the phone is locked or your iPhone app is in the background, the message will be received by the iPhone from the background. Read up on the `openParentApplication` method in the Xcode docs for more information.