# Long-running task performed in foreground is suspended when app enters background

Tags: objective-c, ios, background

When a user first opens my app, I need to download and install some content from a server before they can begin using the app.  The problem is that this takes around 5 minutes on wifi, during which time the app goes into the background and the download is suspended.

Is there any way to either:

- prevent an iOS app from entering the background whilst I perform my download
- or continue peforming the task in the background (i.e. perform the task irrespective of whether the app is in the foreground or background)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really doesn't matter, if the user presses the home button it will go to background. Although you can do two things to mitigate the problem:

- Use `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`, to give you a bit more time to download. Which you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319643/objective-c-proper-use-of-beginbackgroundtaskwithexpirationhandler).
- Don't allow the device to become iddle, with `[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;`. You can read more about that [here](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/core-services/how-to-keep-the-screen-from-locking.html).

Either way, the best thing you can do is to tell the user, that is an important download and he shouldn't quit the application.

Comment: do beginBGTask which will VERY likely not cancel an operation that doesnt do anything but download a file... dont disable idleTimer for that -- IMHO

Comment: You can disable it, and enable it once the download is finished... :S

Comment: Jacky Boy - thanks so much.  You nailed it.  I'm using the idleTimerDisabled = YES command to prevent the app going into the background during the installation.  That's good enough for me.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you include some or all of the content in your app bundle instead, and just download changes on first run?

I can't imagine this is a good first user experience, and it may not pass App Store review like this.

The only third party apps that are allowed to download in the background are newsstand apps loading issue content, and Apple are pretty strict about what they allow as newsstand apps.

Comment: It's an app that needs a local copy of live data so that it can work offline - so the short answer is that it does have to perform the download first.  The good news is that Apple have already approved it, I'm just trying to fix the problem of it timing out on slow connections.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you want, in this situation. One way, and I think the best and only, is to resume your download when you app becomes active (returns to foreground state). Also, don't forget to register for connectivity notifications (Reachability class can be used for this purpose from this Apple sample app http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html). Good Luck!

Comment: I've managed to disable the idleTimer, which means I can do the first of my two options.  If that didn't work, I'd have done a background install (which is valid provided it happens with the first 10 minutes of background processing).  Thanks for your help.

Comment: But, you can't be sure if during those 10 mins your task is completed. Maybe, user will kil your app from bg, maybe connection will be lost when your app was doing bg job, then what? :) So, I really suggest you to implement resuming support. Good Luck once more ;)