# Asynchronous calling in didEnterBackground method

Tags: ios, objective-c

My code:

```
NSMutableArray *sstr = [[DBModel database]getCName];
NSArray *aarr = [[sstr objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@"!"];

acName = [aarr objectAtIndex:0];
acMobileno = [aarr objectAtIndex:1];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:///userstatus.php?name=%@&mobileno=%@&status=off",[aarr objectAtIndex:0],[aarr objectAtIndex:1]]];

NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
[postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *stringBoundary = @"------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",stringBoundary];
[postRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];

//name
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[aarr objectAtIndex:0]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
//mobileno
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"mobileno\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[aarr objectAtIndex:1]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
//status
NSString *status = @"off";
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"status\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",status] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[postRequest setHTTPBody:postBody];

NSData *returndata=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:postRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSString *string1=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:returndata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"OFF Status report = %@",string1);
```

I am running this code with `performSelectorInBackground:` in `didEnterBackground` method.

Sometimes it gives me the strange problem of not updating the table in server.

Is it problem with using `performSelector` in delegate method or should i change this request to asynchronous?

Comment: UI Changes are best done on the main thread. Once you are done with the actions in the Background thread, call the Main Thread again using `- (void)performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait` and update the table..

Comment: Right.. My bad.. I read **updating the table** instead of **updating the table in server**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be **starting** a network request when your app goes to the background.  This means, for example, that when the user closes the app, you begin making a network transaction.  That's not the way Apple intends for apps to work (*ideally*).

From [the documentation on applicationDidEnterBackground:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidEnterBackground) (bold is mine):

> Your implementation of this method **has approximately five seconds to
>   perform any tasks and return**. If you need additional time to perform
>   any final tasks, you can request additional execution time from the
>   system by calling beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:. In
>   practice, you should return from applicationDidEnterBackground: as
>   quickly as possible. If the method does not return before time runs
>   out your application is terminated and purged from memory.

So, you're probably seeing that your network transaction is not always finishing quickly enough.

I'd recommend rethinking your app.  `applicationDidEnterBackground:` is probably not the right time to do this work.  If you really need to do some work in the background, see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10319643/119114) of using a background *task*.  If you put your code in a background task, then you should be able to use `NSURLConnection` either with a synchronous, **or** asynchronous request.

Comment: What method are you talking about?  I only know the `applicationDidEnterBackground:` method.  There is `applicationWillEnterForeground:`, but that's for when the user is **opening** your app again.

Comment: Did you mean `applicationWillResignActive:`?  If so, I would still say, "no".  If you really need to contact your server when the user quits the app, follow the example I linked to showing how to begin a "background task with expiration handler".

Comment: I added some code in didBecomeActiveMethod to perform some updation in server.Is there possibility of getting same error?

Comment: No.  If you put your code in `applicationDidBecomeActive:`, then you will not have the request fail because it doesn't complete within 5 seconds.  Of course, there might be a **different** problem.  You just have to try it and see what happens.