# Creating an online game feature without Server Side logic?

Tags: swift

So im developing a very simple game. Basically I will be using Swift + Firebase.

Users can login in to my game and click a button to fight a "boss". But other users can also fight the same boss "instance".

On my Firebase DB there will be a reference to this "instance" of the "boss" with a certain amount of "life","dmg to players per second", "# of players fighting it".

I will use the Realtime Database to update the "Boss's Life" and "# of Players Fighting it" on each user's `ViewController`.

My question is since the "Boss instance" does "damage per second" how can i make sure thats running even when users put the game in background?

I can put NSTimer in `viewWillAppear()`but I want the player to be damaged even in background and if the player's life reaches 0 -> to save that in DB and note that "player has died" in the DB as well. So when they come back it will run a check and tell them they have died and boot them back to the `Main View Controller`.

Hope this makes sense!

Iv been trying to figure this out for weeks and well now im at a point where i cant skip it!

Comment: there is no way to reliably run an nstimer in the background in iOS. you may have to put users in the backend if you want to do this

Comment: @Jared  hmm Is there a way I can show a UIAlert when they click the "home" button or before they try to go away from my app to warn them if they leave they will be "considered dead"?

Comment: hmm. I am not sure if you can show an alertview, but in your app delegate there is a method called applicationWillResignActive where you can run code before the app goes to the background. edit: yep you definitely cannot show an alert view in that method. maybe warn the user right before they fight the boss?

Comment: hmm so If i use `applicationWillResignActive` i can use setValue on the Firebase DB where the user is located and note "user died"? Does `aplicationWillResignActive` execute only when they leave the app (Home button) or actually close the app? or both?

Comment: there is applicationDidEnterBackground, resignActive, and applicationWillTerminate. You can handle each of these cases differently, or make a method and call it in all these cases. Here are some good docs about each state: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html

Comment: Ok awesome thanks man! Do you think the way im building it is decent? Just curious what kind of backend language could I use to make this easier? I havnt really learned anything besides Swift and Firebase for all my apps. I dont really understand how the backend server will keep "dmging the players" while they are offline or app is closed..

Comment: also note that making database calls in these cases is not consistent with how apple intends them to be used. Look into beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler for the database calls

Comment: But im not using CoreData im using Firebase Realtime Database to update.. would they not accept this app?

Comment: check this answer out and youll be fine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319643/objective-c-proper-use-of-beginbackgroundtaskwithexpirationhandler

Comment: if you want to do this in another language I would check out Ruby on Rails or PHP. But what youre doing is fine and those would add unnecessary complication so keep it up!

Comment: Ok thanks :) Any thoughts on this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37599113/how-to-structure-game-to-add-more-items-to-unlock-later-on