# App performs task in background (after receiving a remote notification), but finishes not completely

Tags: objective-c, background-task, remote-notifications

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

It is being called with `content-available = 1`. A download task starts (shows the `NSLogs`), but it does not complete the called task. Only when switching the app back to Foreground it finishes the previous called task.

Any idea... how this can happen?

Comment: clarify your ques i didnt got ..?

Comment: you mean your api not responding in background ?

Comment: When the app is in the background and a remote push notification comes in, a Parse "getObjectsInBackGround" task is called. This task doesn't finish while the app is in background, but it continues after transition to foreground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use  UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.to perform api call in back ground.

```
       - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {




        isnotificationScreenopen = NO;
        UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTaskId =[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTaskId];
            NSLog(@"%f",[UIApplication sharedApplication].backgroundTimeRemaining);
        }];
        NSLog(@"%f",[UIApplication sharedApplication].backgroundTimeRemaining);



}
```

you can also read this link also

[objective c - Proper use of beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319643/objective-c-proper-use-of-beginbackgroundtaskwithexpirationhandler)