# How to write code that will not pause when user press home button

Tags: ios, swift

I want to implement image sync in my ios app. for this what i have done is

1. take a photo
2. upload that photo to firebase
3. get the firebase stored url and send it to an api server so that server stores that info to a database

It works ok as long as the app is running, but when I exit out from the app pressing home button everything pauses.

So how can run a code that will not pause if app goes to home page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this documentation,

> For tasks that require more execution time to implement, you must
> request specific permissions to run them in the background without
> their being suspended. In iOS, only specific app types are allowed to
> run in the background:

- > Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background,
  > such as a music player app
- > Apps that record audio content while in the
  > background Apps that keep users informed of their location at all
  > times, such as a navigation app
- > Apps that support Voice over Internet
  > Protocol (VoIP) Apps that need to download and process new content
  > regularly
- > Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories
- > Apps that implement these services must declare the services they
  > support and use system frameworks to implement the relevant aspects of
  > those services

> Declaring the services lets the system know which
> services you use, but in some cases it is the system frameworks that
> actually prevent your application from being suspended.

Link: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Here is how to implement (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10319761) by [Ashley Mills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123632/ashley-mills)):

> ```
> func doUpdate () {
>
> dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
>
>     let taskID = beginBackgroundUpdateTask()
>
>     var response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?, request: NSURLRequest?
>
>     let data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &error)
>
>     // Do something with the result
>
>     endBackgroundUpdateTask(taskID)
>
>     })
> }
>
> func beginBackgroundUpdateTask() -> UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier {
>     return UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler({})
> }
>
> func endBackgroundUpdateTask(taskID: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier) {
>     UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(taskID)
> }
> ```

Comment: getting error with swift 3. could u please update the answer

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not experienced with swift programming. The code above was quoted from the answer on SO.

Answer (score 0):

[Swift3] This is kind of worked for me

```
func doUpdate () {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        let taskID = self.beginBackgroundUpdateTask()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(5), execute: {
            print("printing after 10 min")
        })
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.endBackgroundUpdateTask(taskID: taskID)
        }
    }
}


func beginBackgroundUpdateTask() -> UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier {
    return UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: {})
}


func endBackgroundUpdateTask(taskID: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier) {
    UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(taskID)
}
```

Not sure what is the max time for this to complete since i see there is a `expirationHandler`

Comment: As per this tutorial, https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started, In the past, this mode was often used to complete an upload or download and a generous (but not guaranteed) 10 minutes was provided to accomplish these tasks.