# Request times out when comes from background

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

We have an application which relies on network calls from the server.

There is a case (I cannot replicate it) where when the app comes to foreground from the background the network call which was in process before the app went to background times-out. It is the only time which a network call will fail.

Does anyone has an idea why this is happening?

*Alamofire Configuration + Request:*

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 7 // seconds
    AFManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)

AFManager.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).validate().responseString { response in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            print(response)
            completion()
        } else {
            print(response.error!)
            completion()

        }
    }
```

Comment: I see this with AFNetworking and obj-c when I do long polling. The fix is to start a background task when moving in to the background to complete any outstanding requests. You'll have up to about 3 minutes to complete.

Comment: @FryAnEgg I do it in a background process and the network call is small, normally takes 1 sec or so to get a response.

Comment: a background task is different than a bg process or thread. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46567311/cant-start-beginbackgroundtask-swift-3       for code and discussion

Comment: @FryAnEgg I see what you mean, but i do not do any long polling. Also in your solution how did you know which request was executing at the time the user enters the app in background?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem with RequestRetrier from Alamofire and function

```
func retry(_ request: Request,
           for session: Session,
           dueTo error: Error,
           completion: @escaping (RetryResult) -> Void) {
    guard let response = request.task?.response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
        if let index = self.retryingRequests.firstIndex(of: request) {
            self.retryingRequests.remove(at: index)
            return completion(.doNotRetryWithError(error))
        }

        self.retryingRequests.append(request)
        return completion(.retry)
    }


    // Other code for refreshing Auth token
```

When app comes from background, the request will fail, and you will retry it. To avoid infinite loop you need to track your request that have beed already retried.