# Canceling web socket request when moving to background in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, websocket, ios13

So I'm using iOS 13's URLSessionWebSocket functionality.

I have a screen that should send a ping to another socket every X seconds.
Everything works fine until the user moves the app to the background.

Since I don't need to perform any requests in the background, I'm trying to suspend all of the URLSessionWebSocketTasks until the app is back in the foreground.

In my code, I have several tasks stored in socketConnections dictionary.
I also have a BehaviorSubject named "inForeground" that indicates the state.
I'm listening to UIScene's background/foreground notifications and doing this:

```
    @objc func appDidMoveToBackground(_ notification: Notification) {
        inForeground.onNext(false)
        for (taskId, task) in socketConnections {
            task.suspend()
        }
    }
    
    @objc func appDidBecomeActive(_ notification: Notification) {
        inForeground.onNext(true)
        for (id, task) in socketConnections {
            task.resume()
            setReceiveHandler(id)
        }
    }
    
    private func setReceiveHandler(_ taskId: String) {
        guard let foregroundState = try? self.inForeground.value(), foregroundState else {
            print("not in foreground")
            return
        }
        socketConnections[taskId]?.receive { [unowned self] result in
            do {
                let message = try result.get()
                print("\(message)")
                self.setReceiveHandler(taskId)
            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

When I move to background and then foreground, I still get errors:

*nw_read_request_report [C16] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"*

and

*[websocket] Read completed with an error Software caused connection abort*

and then:

*Connection 16: received failure notification*

Any ideas what could go wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that you can not suspend and resume a connection if the application goes to background. You can either keep the connection alive using [backgroundTasks](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623031-beginbackgroundtask), or you can re-structure the logic of your app so it restart your connection from scratch(or both).

The explanation:
When you open a socket connection the kernel/OS is allocating and managing resources(memory, ports) on behalf of your application. This is [freed](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2277/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010841-CH1-SUBSECTION11)* when the application enters background so that it can be used by other apps. So the open connection you had, after the application enters background is not [long valid](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/97824) and can not be re-used, with some very specific exceptions (VOIP apps).

If you choose to ask for more time the OS will allow the connection to stay alive you can find details in [proper-use-of-beginbackgroundtaskwithexpirationhandler](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319643/proper-use-of-beginbackgroundtaskwithexpirationhandler).
But because the background execution time is limited you should build your app is a way that the connections are restarted when needed.